# How to synchronize subproject build number

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins JobA triggers JobB as a subproject.

Is there any way that I can force JobB to have the same build number as JobA?

I am currently passing an environment variable into JobB so that JobB can use the correct number during its build.  But it's still confusing having JobA and JobB have different build numbers.

I am also using the "Next Build Number Plugin", but JobA and JobB's build numbers keep drifting apart over time as JobA fails before it calls JobB, forcing me to come back and manually fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider **[Build Name Setter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Name+Setter+Plugin)**, as it allows setting a `BUILD_NUMBER` through a variable. Configure it to use something like `$parentBuildNumber`

Now, in JobB configure a text/string parameter, `parentBuildNumber`.
When you trigger JobB from JobA, you should be using **[Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin)**.

There configure a predefined parameter set as `parentBuildNumber=$BUILD_NUMBER`

Comment: I already have something like that working.

What I want is something that will set the build number of the jenkins job.

Comment: That **does** set the build number of the job

Answer (score 0):

In the parent job get the next build number, substract by 1 if needed and pass it to child job:

```
cat $JENKINS_HOME/jobs/$JOB_NAME/nextBuildNumber
```

And output it to

```
$JENKINS_HOME/jobs/$CHILD_JOB_NAME/nextBuildNumber
```

You may or may not have to install the [NextBuildNumber](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Next+Build+Number+Plugin) plugin:

Also, there is a CLI command set-next-build-number. Try executing jenkins CLI help.